# Within Eclipse, switch from using the Master branch in the Local Repository to something else

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I created an empty project in Git. I also created a Java EE projcet in Eclipse (note: Eclipse has the Git plug-in installed).

From within Eclipse, I accessed and duplicated the (empty) Git Repository project on my Local Machine (or rather laptop).

I then wrote some code in my Java EE project.

```
From within the project, I then used the Team -> Commit option on it to :
1) Add the project to the Local Repository
2) Commit and push the contents from the Local Repository to the Git Repository.
```

My problem is that all of this work was done using the Master branch.

The Git Repository is currently sitting on the Master branch.
The Local Repository is currently sitting on the Master branch.

Whenever I make changes to the project and do a Team-> Commit, all actions happen with the Master branches.
Master -> Master

```
What I would like to do is as follows: 
1) create 3 more branches in Git Repository (called consolidation, testing, production) - each new branch would be a copy of the Master Branch
2) On the Eclipse side, I need to fix it so that when any changes are made and saved to the Local Repository, the data will be saved to the
    Consolidation Branch of the Local Repository and ~NOT~ the Master Branch (which is what happens now).
3) After saving data in the Consolidation Branch, from then on out, when code is sent to the Git Repository, it would be done by using the Consolidation branch and NOT the Master branch.
```

How can I do this?

TIA

**Update**

@Howlger
Hi and thanks for the response! Your suggestion gave me a clue on how to solve the problem. First, I logged into Git and copied the Master branch to a "dev" branch.

Next, I switched to the Git perspective (locally) under Eclipse and created a "dev" branch for my project:

> Branches -> Switch To -> New Branches

Then, I followed some of your advice except I created a path that would allow for

> branch : dev (local) => branch : dev (remote)

It is under the "Advanced" button.

I did a small test and it worked. Thanks again!

**Update**
Hi again - just logging in to note that I changed the references so that

```
Source Ref = refs/heads/*
Target Ref = refs/heads/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of a local branch to a branch of the remote/upstream repository is specified by the push ref mappings. It looks like your current push ref mapping is `HEAD:refs/heads/master`: your current local branch will be pushed to the remote/upstream repository *master* branch. To map local branches to the remote/upstream repository branches with the same name, just remove all push ref mappings:

1. In the Git Repositories view righ-click the *Remotes > origin > push* node and choose *Configure Push...*
2. Select the mapping and click *Delete*
3. Click *Save*

See [EGit User Guide > Push Ref Specifications](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Ref_Specifications) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out and update post with my results :-)

Comment: Thanks @holwger - your tips gave me clues on how to solve the problem :-)